# Connect Qt signal in dll with C# application

Tags: c#, qt, dll, signals

I have a dll which exports slots and functions, I also have some signals that's emitted from some private functions in the dll. The dll is a COM Component if that helps anything.

Firstly I've exported the complete QT class and can see my public slots and functions when I've added the reference in Visual studio 2010 but I can't see the signals (don't know if I should though). They are declared with "Q_SIGNALS".

What I want is to connect one of these signals to a method in my C# project, Just like a signal to slot in QT but now I need something like "signal (QT)" to "method (C#)", is this possible? any help is appreciated.

```
C++ (Qt)
signals:
  void mySignal(const QString& path);
```

Should be connected to:

```
C# (VS2010)
void myFunction(string path);
```

Comment: There are C# bindings available for Qt which likely solve this issue. (I think the bindings project is called Kyoto.)

Answer (score 1):

You don't see the signals in the exported Qt class, because they are not functions of the class. It's not a C(++) declaration of any kind. Just a named placeholder which is used by Qt preprocessor for generating the calling code, in case that the signal is actually connected somewhere. A signal can then become two different but simple things, depending on the threading context. Whether the signal sending object lives in the same thread as the receiving object:

1. it does: compiled as simple direct method call
2. it does not: the slot call is stored at the receiver's message queue and executed upon the receiver's thread return to the message loop. The "slot" is then what is being also called an "event handler"

So for case 1, you actually don't need the Qt syntax sugar at all. Just simply call your C# method from the point in Qt where you would do `emit mySignal()`. However, case 2 cannot be done as simply as with Qt, because the receiver must inherit QObject (which i am not aware of being possible in C#). You still can roll your own message loop with handlers, but Qt won't help you with it.

Comment: okey, that I get and I also noticed that. How can i "simply call my C# method" from my qt dll? I guess you mean some kind of callback method? I'm trying this now with my COM dll but everytime I add a typedef to my parameter list the function dissapears from exported list...

Comment: Where are you adding the typedef? What function disappears? If your Qt-based dll is a COM, can't you use COM for the interop somehow? I know next to nothing about COM.